# changing the data of a variable on button clicks

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Im trying to change the array inside of a variable by different button click, but im unable to do it. Is there any way i can do this.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  var chartdata = [];
  var eqdata = [['a',2],['b',6],['r',9],['s',8]];
  var debdata =  [['p',2],['r',6],['r',9],['d',8]];
  var hybdata =  [['l',2],['k',6],['rr',9],['df',8]];
  
  function clicked(){
    var id = event.srcElement.id
    if (id = 'eqty'){
        return chartdata = eqdata;
    } else if (id = "debt"){
        return chartdata = debdata;
    } else if (id = "hyb"){
        return chartdata = hybdata;
    }
};
</script>
<div class="row" style="margin:auto; padding: 8px 8px 0" id="categories">
  <button id="eqty" class="btn btn-primary" style='margin: 0 8px' onclick="clicked()">Equity Chart</button>
  <button id="debt" class="btn btn-primary" style='margin: 0 8px' onclick="clicked()">Debt Chart</button>
  <button id="hyb" class="btn btn-primary" style='margin: 0 8px' onclick="clicked()">Hybrid Chart</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, if the `script` tag has a `src` attribute any JS code within the element will be ignored. You need to put your logic in a separate `script` tag. Secondly, what exactly is the output you're trying to achieve? Right now you're returning a boolean from `checked()` which will always be `false`, and you aren't doing anything with it anyway...?

Comment: Im trying to store a particular array declared above in the script tag in the chartdata variable on respective button click. can you tell me hoe to do it properly.

Comment: Ok, so there's a chart too. Where is that defined? How is its data updated? A comlpete example should be provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

there are several wrong things in your code:

1. you shouldn't write your script in an import script (line 1)
2. you should use es6's let and const instead of var
3. in your checks (lines 9, 11 and 13) you should have at least a double equal sign == to compare, one equal sign is used to assign values.

Fixing these little things you should end up with something like this:

```
<div class="row" style="margin:auto; padding: 8px 8px 0" id="categories">
<button id="eqty" class="btn btn-primary" style='margin: 0 8px' onclick="clicked()">Equity Chart</button>
<button id="debt" class="btn btn-primary" style='margin: 0 8px' onclick="clicked()">Debt Chart</button>
<button id="hyb" class="btn btn-primary" style='margin: 0 8px' onclick="clicked()">Hybrid Chart</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let chartdata = [];
    const eqdata = [['a',2],['b',6],['r',9],['s',8]];
    const debdata =  [['p',2],['r',6],['r',9],['d',8]];
    const hybdata =  [['l',2],['k',6],['rr',9],['df',8]];
    
    function clicked(){
        const id = event.srcElement.id
        if (id == 'eqty'){
            chartdata = eqdata;
        } else if (id == "debt"){
            chartdata = debdata;
        } else if (id == "hyb"){
            chartdata = hybdata;
        }
    };
</script>
```